# basic viewPager example with anko

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, anko

I am a complete android newb. I have a basic app that I am building and I would like the user to be able to page (swipe) horizontally through content. I am creating the views with anko. I read the android docs on ViewPager and noticed the anko adapters `viewPager()` and `viewPager {}` etc.

So naively I would assume I could do something like:

```
viewPager {
  verticalLayout{ ... }
  verticalLayout{ ... }
}
```

Where each child of `viewPager{}` would become a tab in the layout.

I haven't managed to get anything working yet. Can any android ninjas provide a minimal example of a viewPager + anko approach?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with anko, but, for me, it's easier to add a viewpager in xml, and then attach an adapter and layoutManager in the onCreate. In the adapter I can then add the pages. Check out this example, it's very simple - https://medium.com/@Abdulkadir98/android-sliding-tabs-with-viewpager-851f9c996cb5